# What are some of the most important conclusions of Game Theory?

Tags: game-theory

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166125/what-kind-of-mathematics-is-required-by-game-theory) post has some good recommendations on prerequisite knowledge. I'm a first-year undergraduate. There are plenty of examples of applications. For example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870792/some-examples-of-applications-of-game-theory). I'm learning through MIT lectures online from [this](http://stellar.mit.edu/S/course/14/fa04/14.12/materials.html) resource.

To really see the big picture and understand Game Theory, I wanted to ask the community what the most important conclusions of Game Theory are. Specifically, results where Game Theory has been used that has created a big impact on the world today.

I stumbled upon the [Prisoner's Dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner%27s_dilemma) while reading *Microeconomics 3e*, by *Paul Krugman, Robin Wells, Iris Au,* and *Jack Parkinson* and that is how I found myself in this dark rabbit hole.

Thanks.

Comment: As your first link suggests, theorems involved with functional analysis are very essential in game theory. However, if you just want to have an overview of game theory, there are plenty of materials you can choose to read. Here is a good overview with simple notations and concepts: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c23d/eff446c17c6b8b4f994224a199db4d14df39.pdf

Comment: And (personally) I guess, for people who study (especially pure) math, game theory itself is already an application.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yao%27s_principle